# Relational Algebra, Selection and Join

Tags: sql, database, join, selection, relational-algebra

How can I write Relational Algebra for the following SQL query?

```
select Singer.*
from Minger join Manager
on Singer.manid = Manager.id
where Manager.name = 'asdf';
```

I have only one idea which is:

```
π a,b,c,d (
    σ Manager.name='asdf' (Singer ⋈ Singer.manid=Manager.id Manager)
)
```

a, b, c and d are the columns of the Singer table.

However, it does not seem optimal to me.

Comment: Do the σ on Manager rather than the join of Manager and Singer. That should limit the number of records you have to join. There may be more, I'm just too rusty with relational algebra.

Comment: What does "optimal" mean?

Comment: You must tell us what "relational algebra" you are using. There is no single "relational" algebra. Give a textbook or other reference and/or describe what operators you are supposed to use. Dotted names are almost certainly not in your algebra.